# python-oracledb module fails to use instantclient in a docker container

Tags: python, oracle, docker, instantclient, python-oracledb

I'm trying to build a docker image to access an oracle database
at runtime, I'm having the following error message: `DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library: "/oracle/instantclient/libclntsh.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory".`

Inside the container, there actually is a symbolic link at `/oracle/instantclient/libclntsh.so`

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.12-slim

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y wget unzip libaio1

ARG ORACLE_HOME=/oracle
ARG ORACLE_CLIENT_HOME=${ORACLE_HOME}/instantclient

# Download and install Oracle instantclient
RUN mkdir /tmp/oracle && \
    wget https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/1920000/instantclient-basic-linux.x64-19.20.0.0.0dbru.zip -P /tmp/oracle && \
    unzip /tmp/oracle/instantclient-basic-* -d /tmp/oracle && \
    mkdir ${ORACLE_HOME} && \
    mv /tmp/oracle/instantclient_* ${ORACLE_CLIENT_HOME}

ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH="${ORACLE_CLIENT_HOME}"

RUN pip install --upgrade pip && \
    pip install pipenv
ENV PIPENV_VENV_IN_PROJECT=1

WORKDIR /app

ADD main.py Pipfile Pipfile.lock ./

RUN pipenv sync

ENTRYPOINT ["./.venv/bin/python", "main.py"]
CMD [""]
```

main.py:

```py
import os

import oracledb


def print_db_version(db_config):
    params = oracledb.ConnectParams(host=db_config['host'], port=db_config['port'], service_name=db_config['name'])
    with oracledb.connect(user=db_config['username'], password=db_config['password'], params=params) as conn:
        print(f'Database version: {conn.version}')
        conn.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Both calls below fail...
    # oracledb.init_oracle_client()
    oracledb.init_oracle_client(os.environ['LD_LIBRARY_PATH'])

    db_config = {
        'host': os.environ['DB_HOST'],
        'port': os.environ['DB_PORT'],
        'name': os.environ['DB_NAME'],
        'username': os.environ['DB_USERNAME'],
        'password': os.environ['DB_PASSWORD'],
    }

    print_db_version(db_config)
```

Pipfile:

```
[[source]]
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"

[packages]
oracledb = "1.4.2"
```

command lines (last one allows to explore the container):

```
docker build -t my-version .
docker run my-version
docker run -it --entrypoint "" my-version bash
```

I can not figure out why this error pops up while the library is actually installed in my container... any ideas?

---

**EDIT**

I tried Anthony Tuininga suggestions and had the following output:

```
ODPI [00001] 2023-10-21 19:13:32.206: ODPI-C 5.0.1
ODPI [00001] 2023-10-21 19:13:32.206: debugging messages initialized at level 64
ODPI [00001] 2023-10-21 19:13:32.206: Context Parameters:
ODPI [00001] 2023-10-21 19:13:32.206:     Oracle Client Lib Dir: /oracle/instantclient
ODPI [00001] 2023-10-21 19:13:32.206: Environment Variables:
ODPI [00001] 2023-10-21 19:13:32.206:     LD_LIBRARY_PATH => "/oracle/instantclient"
ODPI [00001] 2023-10-21 19:13:32.206: load in parameter directory
ODPI [00001] 2023-10-21 19:13:32.206: load in dir /oracle/instantclient
ODPI [00001] 2023-10-21 19:13:32.206: load with name /oracle/instantclient/libclntsh.so
ODPI [00001] 2023-10-21 19:13:32.206: load by OS failure: /oracle/instantclient/libclntsh.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
ODPI [00001] 2023-10-21 19:13:32.206: load with name /oracle/instantclient/libclntsh.so.19.1
ODPI [00001] 2023-10-21 19:13:32.207: load by OS failure: /oracle/instantclient/libclntsh.so.19.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
ODPI [00001] 2023-10-21 19:13:32.207: load with name /oracle/instantclient/libclntsh.so.18.1
ODPI [00001] 2023-10-21 19:13:32.207: load by OS failure: /oracle/instantclient/libclntsh.so.18.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
ODPI [00001] 2023-10-21 19:13:32.207: load with name /oracle/instantclient/libclntsh.so.12.1
ODPI [00001] 2023-10-21 19:13:32.207: load by OS failure: /oracle/instantclient/libclntsh.so.12.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
ODPI [00001] 2023-10-21 19:13:32.207: load with name /oracle/instantclient/libclntsh.so.11.1
ODPI [00001] 2023-10-21 19:13:32.207: load by OS failure: /oracle/instantclient/libclntsh.so.11.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
ODPI [00001] 2023-10-21 19:13:32.207: load with name /oracle/instantclient/libclntsh.so.20.1
ODPI [00001] 2023-10-21 19:13:32.207: load by OS failure: /oracle/instantclient/libclntsh.so.20.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
ODPI [00001] 2023-10-21 19:13:32.207: load with name /oracle/instantclient/libclntsh.so.21.1
ODPI [00001] 2023-10-21 19:13:32.207: load by OS failure: /oracle/instantclient/libclntsh.so.21.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/main.py", line 18, in <module>
['libocci.so.19.1', 'libnnz19.so', 'adrci', 'libipc1.so', 'xstreams.jar', 'libclntsh.so.11.1', 'libclntsh.so.18.1', 'genezi', 'libocci.so.12.1', 'network', 'libocci.so.10.1', 'libocci.so', 'libociei.so', 'libclntsh.so', 'libclntsh.so.12.1', 'libocci.so.18.1', 'libclntsh.so.19.1', 'ucp.jar', 'BASIC_LICENSE', 'libocijdbc19.so', 'ojdbc8.jar', 'BASIC_README', 'libmql1.so', 'liboramysql19.so', 'libocci.so.11.1', 'libclntshcore.so.19.1', 'libclntsh.so.10.1', 'uidrvci']
    oracledb.init_oracle_client(os.environ['LD_LIBRARY_PATH'])
  File "src/oracledb/impl/thick/utils.pyx", line 476, in oracledb.thick_impl.init_oracle_client
  File "src/oracledb/impl/thick/utils.pyx", line 500, in oracledb.thick_impl.init_oracle_client
  File "src/oracledb/impl/thick/utils.pyx", line 421, in oracledb.thick_impl._raise_from_info
oracledb.exceptions.DatabaseError: DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library: "/oracle/instantclient/libclntsh.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory". See https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/initialization.html for help
```

It shows that:

- `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is properly set to `/oracle/instantclient`
- the instant client is actually searched in this directory
- `/oracle/instantclient` actually contains libclntsh.so file (it's actually a symbolic link to libclntsh.so.19.1

It sounds pretty weird to me...

I made the source code available here: https://github.com/galak75/python-oracle-img

---

**EDIT 2**

I tried to use the bare call to `init_oracle_client()`, and then it looks like `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable is not used: instant client is search in my python virtualenv:

```
ODPI [00001] 2023-10-22 14:48:34.681: ODPI-C 5.0.1
ODPI [00001] 2023-10-22 14:48:34.681: debugging messages initialized at level 64
ODPI [00001] 2023-10-22 14:48:34.681: Context Parameters:
ODPI [00001] 2023-10-22 14:48:34.681: Environment Variables:
ODPI [00001] 2023-10-22 14:48:34.681:     LD_LIBRARY_PATH => "/oracle/instantclient"
ODPI [00001] 2023-10-22 14:48:34.681: check module directory
ODPI [00001] 2023-10-22 14:48:34.681: module name is /app/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/oracledb/thick_impl.cpython-312-aarch64-linux-gnu.so
ODPI [00001] 2023-10-22 14:48:34.681: load in dir /app/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/oracledb
ODPI [00001] 2023-10-22 14:48:34.681: load with name /app/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/oracledb/libclntsh.so
ODPI [00001] 2023-10-22 14:48:34.681: load by OS failure: /app/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/oracledb/libclntsh.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
ODPI [00001] 2023-10-22 14:48:34.681: load with OS search heuristics
ODPI [00001] 2023-10-22 14:48:34.681: load with name libclntsh.so
ODPI [00001] 2023-10-22 14:48:34.682: load by OS failure: libaio.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
ODPI [00001] 2023-10-22 14:48:34.682: load with name libclntsh.so.19.1
ODPI [00001] 2023-10-22 14:48:34.682: load by OS failure: libaio.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
ODPI [00001] 2023-10-22 14:48:34.682: load with name libclntsh.so.18.1
ODPI [00001] 2023-10-22 14:48:34.682: load by OS failure: libaio.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
ODPI [00001] 2023-10-22 14:48:34.682: load with name libclntsh.so.12.1
ODPI [00001] 2023-10-22 14:48:34.683: load by OS failure: libaio.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
ODPI [00001] 2023-10-22 14:48:34.683: load with name libclntsh.so.11.1
ODPI [00001] 2023-10-22 14:48:34.683: load by OS failure: libaio.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
ODPI [00001] 2023-10-22 14:48:34.683: load with name libclntsh.so.20.1
ODPI [00001] 2023-10-22 14:48:34.683: load by OS failure: libclntsh.so.20.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
ODPI [00001] 2023-10-22 14:48:34.683: load with name libclntsh.so.21.1
ODPI [00001] 2023-10-22 14:48:34.683: load by OS failure: libclntsh.so.21.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
ODPI [00001] 2023-10-22 14:48:34.683: check ORACLE_HOME
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/main.py", line 19, in <module>
    oracledb.init_oracle_client()
  File "src/oracledb/impl/thick/utils.pyx", line 476, in oracledb.thick_impl.init_oracle_client
LD_LIBRARY_PATH = /oracle/instantclient
['libocci.so.19.1', 'libnnz19.so', 'adrci', 'xstreams.jar', 'libclntsh.so.11.1', 'libclntsh.so.18.1', 'genezi', 'libocci.so.12.1', 'network', 'libocci.so.10.1', 'libocci.so', 'libociei.so', 'libclntsh.so', 'libclntsh.so.12.1', 'libocci.so.18.1', 'libclntsh.so.19.1', 'ucp.jar', 'BASIC_LICENSE', 'libocijdbc19.so', 'ojdbc8.jar', 'BASIC_README', 'liboramysql19.so', 'libocci.so.11.1', 'libclntshcore.so.19.1', 'libclntsh.so.10.1', 'uidrvci']
  File "src/oracledb/impl/thick/utils.pyx", line 500, in oracledb.thick_impl.init_oracle_client
  File "src/oracledb/impl/thick/utils.pyx", line 421, in oracledb.thick_impl._raise_from_info
oracledb.exceptions.DatabaseError: DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library: "libaio.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory". See https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/initialization.html for help
```

---

**EDIT 3**

I added `libaio1` package installation to my code, since it was clearly the next issue (after the target OS platform issue), as pointed out by [Christopher's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77342237/3216318)

Comment: I tried to downgrade to instant client 11.2, also tried to downgrade to cx-Oracle 8.3.0 and 8.1.0, also tried to downgrade to python 3.8, also tried to downgrade to debian bullseye... always had the same issue... I thought I necessarily have an issue in my setup... and finally got it : the docker host architecture (aarch64), vs instantclient distribution (amd64)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out, after so many hours struggling!

I'm running on a MacBook with an M1 chip (`arm64` architecture), while I'm installing an instantclient distribution for `amd64` architectures...

then I made it work by forcing the target docker platform to `amd64`:

```
docker build -t my-version . --platform amd64
docker run --env-file .local/env my-version
```

**Note**: I also had to fix few issues like installing `libaio1` debian package, and removing the `conn.close()` python statement

---

**EDIT:** Another solution is to download the right instant client package depending on the target OS platform:

```
RUN mkdir /tmp/oracle && \
    if [ "`uname -m`" = "aarch64" ] || [ "`uname -m`" = "arm64" ]; \
      then echo "ARM64 architecture detected" && wget https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/1919000/instantclient-basic-linux.arm64-19.19.0.0.0dbru.zip -P /tmp/oracle; \
    elif [ "`uname -m`" = "amd64" ] || [ "`uname -m`" = "x86_64" ] ; \
      then echo "AMD64 architecture detected" && wget https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/1920000/instantclient-basic-linux.x64-19.20.0.0.0dbru.zip -P /tmp/oracle; \
    else  \
      echo "target platform was not recognized : `uname -a`" && exit 1; \
    fi; \
    unzip /tmp/oracle/instantclient-basic-* -d /tmp/oracle && \
    mkdir -p ${ORACLE_CLIENT_HOME} && \
    mv /tmp/oracle/instantclient_*/* ${ORACLE_CLIENT_HOME}
```

Comment: A note to other readers: if you use python-oracledb's default "Thin" mode, you don't need to install Oracle Instant Client.

Comment: @ChristopherJones : thank you for the note. You're right, it is much easier to use the thin mode when possible. In my case, I could not make it work to query spatial data in an old Oracle 11g instance

Answer (score 2):

If you do not require thick mode you can avoid the error completely by simply removing the call to `init_oracle_client()`.

If you do require it because of limitations in thin mode, set the environment variable `DPI_DEBUG_LEVEL` to the value 64 before running your script. That may help you diagnose the issue. If not, include the output in your question and I'll take a look.

[UPDATE: with the output provided it is clear that the aio library is missing as also suggested by Chris in his answer. Add that library and your issues should disappear!]

It may also be helpful to list the files found in the directory using `os.listdir(os.environ["LD_LIBRARY_PATH"])`.

Note that the library directory cannot be specified on Linux so you must use the bare call to `init_oracle_client()`.

Comment: thank you for your answer @anthony-tuininga
I tried your suggestions and added the result output to my question. It printed some more information, but my issue remains a mystery to me... :-/

Comment: In your case the output is clearly stating that the aio library is missing -- as Chris also mentioned in his answer!

Comment: Thank you; that was definitely the next issue (after the os-platform issue). 
I will fix this in the question, since it was not the root cause of my problem

Answer (score 0):

For reference, see [Docker for Oracle Database Applications in Node.js and Python](https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/post/part-1-docker-for-oracle-database-applications-in-nodejs-and-python).

When I tried your Dockerfile I got a fairly clear message that the libaio package wasn't installed.

The next issue (other than the missing lock file!) was that main.py is using a context manager for the connection but also explicitly closing the connection.

This Dockerfile works for me:

```
FROM python:3.12-slim

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y wget unzip libaio1

ARG ORACLE_CLIENT_HOME=/opt/oracle/instantclient

WORKDIR /opt/oracle

# Download and install Oracle instantclient
RUN mkdir /tmp/oracle && \
    wget https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/1921000/instantclient-basic-linux.x64-19.21.0.0.0dbru.zip -P /tmp/oracle && \
    unzip /tmp/oracle/instantclient-basic-* -d /tmp/oracle && \
    mv /tmp/oracle/instantclient_* ${ORACLE_CLIENT_HOME} && \
    cd ${ORACLE_CLIENT_HOME} && rm -f *jdbc* *occi* *mysql* *jar uidrvci genezi adrci && \
    echo ${ORACLE_CLIENT_HOME} > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle-instantclient.conf && \
    ldconfig

RUN pip install --upgrade pip && pip install oracledb

WORKDIR /app
ADD main.py ./

CMD ["python", "main.py"]
```

Note I removed the overloaded use of ORACLE_HOME, since this has a specific meaning in Oracle. I also just used python directly, since presumably the container is only going to run one app environment.

I also prefer ldconfig to LD_LIBRARY_PATH since the latter is prone to various issues.

`main.py` is:

```
import os

import oracledb


def print_db_version(db_config):
    params = oracledb.ConnectParams(host=db_config['host'], port=db_config['port'], service_name=db_config['name'])
    with oracledb.connect(user=db_config['username'], password=db_config['password'], params=params) as conn:
        print(f'Database version: {conn.version}')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    oracledb.init_oracle_client()

    db_config = {
        'host': 'whatever',
        'port': 1521,
        'name': 'orclpdb1',
        'username': 'cj',
        'password': 'cj',
    }

    print_db_version(db_config)
```

Follow Anthony's advice about not passing `lib_dir` to `init_oracle_client()` on Linux.

Output is like:

```
$ docker run my-version
Database version: 21.3.0.0.0
```

Finally you should revisit which user you are running in the container.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You're right: libaio1 was actually missing, but I had first an issue with my host architecture (MacOS M1 chip).
For sure, I will revisit which user is running the container: I just wanted to have the simplest example possible to isolate my issue.
Thank you for your help and these clever advices

Comment: Hi @christopher-jones
I'm currently including your suggestion about ldconfig, and I wonder why you remove several files from instant client installation folder. Would I need some of them for more complex requests? (e.g.: GIS requests)

Comment: node-oracledb uses Oracle's OCI API.  The files I removed are not needed for OCI. You could also explore using Basic Light.